What kind of network infrastructure is needed to use the internet supplied by the apartment management thru an ethernet port on the wall?
Recently, I moved to an apartment where internet access is provided by the building management thru an ethernet port on the wall. There are no other ports or wireless signals.
So far, I have always used modems with built-in routers/access points provided by my ISP, either fiber optic modems, ADSL, or cable TV internet modem, whatever service is available in the neighborhood. Therefore, I didn't need to think about any network hardware.
As a temporary solution, I connected my old laptop to the ethernet on the wall and activated the mobile hotspot feature of Windows. This setup allows all of my devices to access the internet, although maybe it's not as efficient or as fast as a proper network setup.
Obviously, some devices at home environment need Wi-Fi, such as smartphones. Some might need ethernet connection (desktop pc's). So, what kind of network infra is suited for this kind of situation?

A router with built-in Wi-Fi and extra ethernet ports. I assume most (if not all) routers are capable of receiving internet on the first Ethernet port and transmitting it via other ports and Wi-Fi simultaneously.

An access point that simply converts the Ethernet on the wall to Wi-Fi. Most access points I see use PoE, which requires an extra adapter to add power to the Ethernet line. Maybe being able to install them on the ceiling is an advantage?

A switch and an access point for extra ethernet ports plus wifi?


In summary, I'm not sure if a non-professional home network needs a full router or just an access point, to best utilize a building-provided internet connection. A common use of a local home network might be to share content between devices, does that need a router, or just an access point is enough?

Although you could probably get all your devices online with just a Wi-Fi AP and maybe a switch, you need a router for the sake of its NAT gateway or firewall features to provide a little privacy for your own network, separating it from the networks of everyone else in your building (unless the building's network is already set up to keep everyone's traffic separate). Without a router separating your network from the rest of the building's network, you and your neighbors could end up seeing and being able to see and print to each others printers, see and stream to each other's TV devices, etc.

I guess my old laptop is acting as a router now and hiding all my other devices behind a single IP right?

I would even say it is the complete opposite of what the "hardware shopping recommendations" close reason was meant to be used for. I still remember when the rule was introduced, and the original intent was to avoid questions that ask for specific products and models – not because of hardware per se, but because models get out of date quick – and the relevant help page even explicitly encouraged the more generic "what kind of device do I need to achieve X" or "what features should I look for" topics that are now being closed left and right.

@Spiff there is no chance of gettng "double natting" right? I assume other residents just plugged in a router and let it go.

@uylmz When you plug directly in, do you get an RFC 1918 private IP address, or a CGNAT address, or a publicly routable address? If you get a public address, you're unlikely to be behind a NAT. Even if your building already puts you behind a NAT, this is an exception where double-NAT might be the way to make the best of a bad situation. You're right, other residents probably did plug in a NAT gateway router and let it go. It's not a bad choice given what you've shared so far.

@Spiff Thanks for replying! I checked the IP address of my old laptop hooked to the ethernet port, Windows shows IP address as 192.168.210.3 and dns server is 192.168.210.254. Btw I turned on network discovery and network tab only shows the laptop itself. When I was at work I used to see other people's pcs there at the workplace.

A router is probably the best choice, as it isolates your apartment's network from your neighbors' – both by the fact that it's a router ("device discovery" packets don't go through routers) and because it almost always comes with a firewall built-in (preventing unwanted inbound connections).
It's probably also what the building's network expects; its DHCP pool might have been configured with the assumption that each tenant will only need one IP address (that is, there's a high chance they just went with the default of /24).

That being said, nearly all home routers are made against the same template. They all have LAN ports bridged together (literally an internal Ethernet switch), and they all have Wi-Fi bridged to that.
So you can use them as a router by connecting Ethernet to the 'WAN' port as documented, or you can also use them as a plain access point/switch just by completely ignoring the 'WAN' port (and turning off the DHCP service, and making very sure you've turned off the DHCP service).
(Some of them explicitly have an "access point" mode that switches the 'WAN' port to be non-routed as well, but that's not strictly necessary.)

Acquire an access point that simply converts the Ethernet on the wall to Wi-Fi. Most access points I see use PoE, which requires an extra adapter to add power to the Ethernet line. However, if this is a better option, I might go for it. Is being able to mount it on the ceiling worth the investment?

Many of them have the adapter bundled; they can also be powered by a PoE-capable switch. Generally, though, it depends on whether you only plan on having one, or 3+.
